Higher power consumption on battery compared to adapter
I've a problem with the power consumption on battery, I get higher power consumption on battery compared to adapter:

On Windows 10 and 11 I get around 4-5 watts of power consumption when idle vs 4-5 watts on adapter
On "Try Ubuntu" without installation, I get a discharge rate (reported by power statistics app) of 7-9 watts when idle vs 4-5 watts on adapter
After installing Ubuntu and then booting I get a discharge rate (again, reported by power statistics app) of 18-43 watts when idle vs 4-5 watts on adapter

I tried the following:

Using "Minimal installation option"
Using both Ubuntu-provided drivers and third-party drivers (during installation)
Using 24.04 and 24.10
Using different power plans

I have a laptop with the following specs:

HP elitebook 845 G10
Ryzen 5 7540u
Radeom 740m
16 gigs of ram
500gb of NVMe SSD

